# RStudio not opening a script

Tags: r, rstudio

I've got an issue with my RStudio IDE. It currently won't open a pre-existing script file. 
When I select it for opening it will open up a new script tab with the given name of the script I want but without any contents.

Also, when I open up the script as a text file the contents are present and intact.

Any ideas on what I need to do to get Rstudio to properly read my script?

Thanks

Comment: Try a daily build then http://dailies.rstudio.com/

Comment: Thanks! That did it!